# Missing code sign certificate when trying to deploy app to new TestFlight

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, testflight, ios-provisioning

We've been developing an app based on Appcelerator Titanium the last couple of months and to deploy the app to our testers, we've used TestFlight. Now, Apple have shut down the "old" TestFlight and integrated it into ItunesConnect.

Now we want to deploy an update to our testers. So we created a new app within Itunes Connect with the same app bundle as the app bundle the provisioning profile we're building the app with are using. We build an IPA file which we try to deploy using Apples tool "Application Loader".

When we try to deploy the app, we get the following error:

```
ERROR ITMS-90161: "Invalid Provisioning Profile. The provisioning profile included in the bundle nu.kodfabriken.ourapp [Payload/OurApp.app]" is invalid. [Missing code-signing certificate.] For more information, visit the iOS Developer Portal"
```

Some Googling and trial-and-error told us to recreate our certificates and provisioning profiles. So we did, and got the same result. We don't know what to do here. Feels like we are stuck, with no clue what to do.

Worth noting is that when Apple switched to "new TestFlight" we didn't change anything at first. We used the very same provisioning profiles as we used with old TestFlight, which worked.

What are we doing wrong? Is this somehow related to how Titanium packages the apps (as far as I know, it's actually Xcode which creates the final build)?